# MySQL Older than 6 months in linked tables

Tags: mysql, date

I have a table of orders which has a customer number and a date finished. I am trying to run a query to see which customers have not ordered for 6 months. I tried the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
orders.Customer,
Max(orders.DateFinished)
FROM
orders
WHERE
DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), Max(orders.DateFinished)) > 180;
GROUP BY
orders.Customer
```

but I am getting a

> [Err] 1111 - Invalid use of group function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Customer,
       Max(DateFinished)
FROM orders
GROUP BY Customer
HAVING sum(DateFinished > CURDATE() - interval 180 day) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

`try like this`

```
SELECT DISTINCT orders.Customer, orders.DateFinished FROM orders 
WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), Max(orders.DateFinished)) > 180
GROUP BY orders.Customer,orders.DateFinished
```

OR

```
select DISTINCT orders.Customer, orders.DateFinished
  from orders
 where orders.DateFinished >= date_sub(orders.DateFinished, interval 6 month);
```